# how can i add validation to a spring boot rest endpoint with a string parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

how to validate a spring boot rest endpoint with a String parameter, here is the sample of my endpoint.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getProfile(@RequestBody @Valid @NotEmpty String profileId){}
```

even thought i added `@valid` and `@NonEmpty` constraint its not getting validated.

but its working for a other classes. for eg,

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveProfiles", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProfiles(@RequestBody @Valid PersistProfilesRequest request){}
```

here all the fields in PersistProfilesRequest class which have a constrain applied is validating properly.

validation is not happening for method parameter with java class like String and Map.

i am using `spring boot 1.3.0` with hibernate validator.

how can i add validation to a rest endpoint with a string parameter?

EDIT

i am using junit and mockmvc to test the endpoint, below is the test case

```
@Test
public void testGetProfile() throws Exception{

    String profileId = "   ";

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/getProfile").content(profileId).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType("application/json"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());

}
```

Comment: is `profileId` coming as `requestBody` ?

Comment: yes profileId is coming as request body, its just string not a key value pair

Comment: Could you show requestBody call with javascript please?

Comment: Hello there. Could you please explain what you're expecting about `@RequestBody @Valid String` ? What is the validation ? I think you should use [`@RequestBody(required = true)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html#required--) instead.

Comment: Mickael,
"public @interface RequestBody {
    boolean required() default true;
}"
Its by default true

Comment: putting @RequestBody(required = true) will it validate with a constraint? suppose if i want to validate profileId as Email (@Email), how can i do that?

Comment: @SarathS i see a couple of things that you can try to make it work.

 i don't think you should be specifying that your `content-type` is `aaplication/json` since you're not actually sending a valid json. 

Also, I would expect from a non valid `@RequestBody` a 400 Bad Request. Therefore, i would use `.andExpect(status().isBadRequest())`. Finally, i think that @Valid have to be used with classes annotated with other Annotations from the Specification. You might just try to use `@NotNull only and see if that works.

Comment: @SarathS i Updated answer please validate if it is clear for you .Thanks

Comment: Did you annotate your controller with @Validated?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, the controller have  Validated annotation

Answer (score 1):

You can try to annotate your controller class with @Validated. In my case it helped.

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/somethin")
public class LegacyRestController {
```

Comment: is the java validation framework and the hibernate Validator work only for bean ?

Comment: No actually not. Validation annotations and their validators are used mostly for base types. @NotEmpty can be used for strings and collections. In your case there is something different cause to not validate those parameters. Tomorrow I can look my own project again if I did some extra configuration for that.

Comment: Oh I see the problem, try to change your method as GET (instead of Post) and change replace '@RequestBody' with '@RequestParam'.

Comment: here is the annotation in controller class, --- 
Validated
RestController
RequestMapping("/kvassist")
ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.profile" })

Comment: updated endpoint declaration to this --  ResponseBody
RequestMapping(value = "/getProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getProfile(@RequestParam(name="p") Valid Email String profileId)